# Download file after authenticated through WebBrowser

Tags: vb.net, download, webbrowser-control, webclient

**Background**

So I am creating a VB .NET program that will basically login to a web page, do a bunch of button clicking, which results in the website generating an excel report that can be downloaded. I have successfully gone through all the steps to produce the file so now I am trying to create a method that will download the file behind the scenes without the "Save as" dialog appearing.

**Details**

I have managed to trap the download through the Navigating event of the Webbrowser control:

```
Public Sub a(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigating
    'intercept the excel download. Retrieve the url but cancel dialog
    If e.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("fmsdownload") Then
        Label3.Text = e.Url.AbsoluteUri
        e.Cancel = True
        'e.Url.AbsoluteUri = the temporarily generated file URL to download from
        'INSERT DOWNLOAD METHOD HERE
    End If
End Sub
```

I verified that the `e.Url.AbsoluteUri` is indeed the correct path. If I copy / paste this URL into Chrome, it downloads.

**Question**

So ultimately I am simply trying to find a way to download the file after the download link has been generated. Please take a look in the section below for what I have tried as I believe I am close to achieving success.

**What I have tried (Please read before posting)**

- Method 1: `My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(URL,SAVEPATH)`. This results in the server kicking back `The repote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden`. This leads me to understand that the authentication isn't being passed which makes sense.
- Method 2: I read on a stackoverflow post to try the URLMON to initiate the download (http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/urlmon/URLDownloadToFile%20.html). I thought that this would have some promise but results in the error `Unable to find an entry point named URLDownloadToFile in DLL 'URLMON.dll'` Here is the code I have used for this method as it may be something simple I am missing:

  ```
  Private Declare Sub URLDownloadToFile _
  Lib "URLMON.dll" (
  ByVal lpCaller As Long,
  ByVal szUrl As String,
  ByVal szFilename As String,
  ByVal dwReserved As Long,
  ByVal lpBindStatusCallback As Long)

  Public Sub a(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigating
   'intercept the excel download. Retrieve the url but cancel dialog
   If e.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("fmsdownload") Then
       Label3.Text = e.Url.AbsoluteUri
       e.Cancel = True

       Try
           Kill(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\download.xls")
       Catch
       End Try

       URLDownloadToFile(0, e.Url.AbsoluteUri, My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\download.xls", 0, 0)

   End If
  ```

  End Sub
- Method 3: After some research it seems like the authentication is stored as cookies so I tried to retrieve the cookies and then provide them back to the WebClient since WebClient supports downloading files. Here is where I capture the cookies:

  ```
  Dim cookie_collection() As String
  Public Sub webbrowser1_documentcompleted(sender As Object, e As 
  WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

   If WebBrowser1.Document.Cookie Is Nothing Then
   Else
       Dim cookies As String() = WebBrowser1.Document.Cookie.Split({";"c}, StringSplitOptions.None)

       For Each cookie As String In cookies
           Dim name As String = cookie.Substring(0, cookie.IndexOf("="c)).TrimStart(" "c)
           Dim value As String = cookie.Substring(cookie.IndexOf("="c) + 1)
           If cookie_collection Is Nothing Then
               ReDim cookie_collection(0)
           Else
               ReDim Preserve cookie_collection(cookie_collection.Length)
           End If
           cookie_collection(cookie_collection.Length - 1) = cookie
           ' MsgBox(cookie)
       Next cookie
   End If


   End Sub
  ```

I verified that two cookies are captured during the authentication process:

[image]

So I try to reapply the cookies to my WebClient before downloading:

```
   Public Sub a(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigating
    'intercept the excel download. Retrieve the url but cancel dialog
    If e.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("fmsdownload") Then
        Label3.Text = e.Url.AbsoluteUri
        e.Cancel = True

        Dim client As New System.Net.WebClient
        For Each cookie As String In cookie_collection
            client.Headers.Add(Net.HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookie)
        Next

        client.DownloadFile(e.Url.AbsoluteUri, My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\download.xls")

    End If
End Sub
```

This unfortunately results in the same error as before `The repote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden` which makes me realize the authentication isn't being passed still.

I know this is a big post but I feel like method 2 or method 3 should work so it may be possible I am missing something small (I hope).

Answer (score 0):

In your last bit of code, where you use `WebClient` to retrieve the file, you currently  add the cookies to the request as follows:

```
For Each cookie As String In cookie_collection
    client.Headers.Add(Net.HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookie)
Next
```

However, there is only a single parameter in HTTP that includes **all cookies at once**, therefore you were overriding the previous cookies by pushing a new header for each cookie. You therefore do not need to extract the cookies by using String.Split, but rather pass the parameter with semicolons as it is, since HTTP should work everything out. Hope this solves your issue!

Edit: Here is what I think might work out:
Retrieve the cookies in the `DocumentCompleted` event like this (third bit of code):

```
Dim cookie_collection As String
Public Sub webbrowser1_documentcompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    If WebBrowser1.Document.Cookie IsNot Nothing Then
       Dim cookies As String = WebBrowser1.Document.Cookie
       If cookie_collection = "" Then
           cookie_collection = cookies
       Else
           cookie_collection &= ";" & cookies
       End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Then proceed by simply passing the `cookie_collection` field to the header:

```
...
Dim client As New System.Net.WebClient
client.Headers.Add(Net.HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookie_collection)
client.DownloadFile(e.Url.AbsoluteUri, My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\download.xls")
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried to replace my initial code but get the Forbidden error still. Am I missing something else?:     `If WebBrowser1.Document.Cookie Is Nothing Then
        Else
            Dim cookie As String = WebBrowser1.Document.Cookie
            If cookie_collection Is Nothing Then
                    ReDim cookie_collection(0)
                Else
                    ReDim Preserve cookie_collection(cookie_collection.Length)
                End If
                cookie_collection(cookie_collection.Length - 1) = cookie
        End If`

Comment: I actually meant the last bit of code instead of the thrid, sorry for that! Just edited it.

Comment: Not a problem but unfortunately no dice. I still get the Forbidden error. Here is my resulting header: `Cookie: csrf_cookie=ade98ec8-1558-4517-b5ea-3d1a4507bf5f; JSESSIONID=iyay4Wex2KcqxCr-wBjn19LF1FvbxvumPbbpdV7v-kZuOSKFxoCi!147640388!-765605226;csrf_cookie=10150dc2-5b65-4b62-a27a-d934baedb187; JSESSIONID=iyay4Wex2KcqxCr-wBjn19LF1FvbxvumPbbpdV7v-kZuOSKFxoCi!147640388!-765605226`  Do you think it is a problem that `csrf_cookie` and `JSESSIONID` are getting set twice?

Comment: FYI, I tried manipulating it so just the first set of cookies are loaded as well as just the second set of cookies and still a Forbidden error..

Comment: That is unfortunate... but downloading the file via the `WebBrowser` works fine, I assume? Have you tried capturing cookies set by the manual downloading process via `WebBrowser` and see whether they differ? Also, the only parameter that appears to be constant is `JSESSIONID`, so maybe try passing only this parameter as the only cookie. If still nothing works, the issue might perhaps be not related to the cookies, but to a different authentication failure, such as HTTP authentication (though I think this is not very likely)

Comment: I will try setting only `JSESSIONID` next but how do I "capture the cookies set by the manual downloading process via WebBrowser"? I thought I was doing this by listening under the WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted event and grabbing the cookies each time?

Comment: I suggest you use a regular browser for this purpose, when the site opens, open the element inspector and switch to the network analysis tab. Then proceed towards downloading the file until it appears in the network analysis table. Now you can inspect each request and its response. You then can see which cookies and other parameters are sent to the server along with the request, as well as what cookies are placed by the request on your computer (`set-coookie` response header). With that information, you should be able to work out which parameters are missing.

Comment: Thanks so much for your advice. I only see `csrf_cookie` and `JSESSIONID` being set as far as cookies unfortunately.... :(

Comment: That's unfortunate... I tried this method myself, with a different site of course and it went fine, accepted the cookies as authentication. What you could do (if you don't need the user to interact with the website) is trying not to use WebBrowser at all, or using a different, more sophisticated WebBrowser control that allows you to do what you want

Comment: You are probably right. I will start looking at other webbrowser controls or other ways to accomplish what I want. Thank you so much for all your help!